# C program not printing out correct output

Tags: c, function

I have written the following code to compute the roots of a quadratic equation:

```
int quadroots(int *ap, int *bp, int *cp,int *root1p, int *root2p, int *dp);
int main (void) {
    int ap,bp,cp;
    int dp, root1p, root2p;
    quadroots(&ap, &bp, &cp, &root1p, &root2p, &dp);
    printf("The solutions are: %f, %f", root1p, root2p);
    }

int quadroots(int *ap, int *bp, int *cp,int *root1p, int *root2p, int *dp){
    int a, b, c, d, root1, root2;
    printf("Enter a, b, c \n");
    scanf("%d, %d, %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a==0) {
        printf ("The system is linear. The roots cannot be computed using this program: a cannot be 0. Please recompile");

    return 0;
    }
    int b_sqared = b*b;

    d = b_sqared - (4 * a * c);

    if (d<0) {

    d=-d;
    printf("The roots of this equation are the complex numbers: \n");
    printf("%.3f+%.3fi", ((-b) / (2*a)), (sqrt(d) / (2 * a)));
    printf(", %.3f%.3fi", (-b / (2*a)), (-sqrt(d) / (2*a)));

    }

    else if (d==0) {
        printf("The root of this equation are real and equal. \n");

        root1= (-d / (2*a));
        printf("The roots of this equation are: %.3f, %.3f", root1, root1);
        }

    else {

        printf ("The roots of the quadratic equation are real numbers. \n");
        root1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) /  (2*a);    
        root2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2*a);

        printf("Roots of the quadratic equation are the real numbers %.3f, %.3f", root1,root2);

        }

    return 0;
    *root1p=root1;
    *root2p=root2;   
}
```

This is based off a code I had previously written which worked, but back then, I wasn't using functions.

As it is now, it compiles and runs fine (ie. it takes in the numbers and performs a calculation), but the answer it prints out is totally incorrect.

Eg. for the input "1 5 6" (corresponding to the equation x^2 +5x + 6, it should print out " The roots are real numbers.
The roots are the real numbers 6 and 1" 
since those are the roots of the equation. However, it doesn't. What is printed are some absurdly huge numbers (Enter a, b, c
1 5 6
The roots of this equation are the complex numbers:
-2719010580126301300000000000.000+0.000i, -2719010580126301300000000000.0000.000iThe solutions are: 0.000000, 0.000000)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much! Best.

Comment: For some specified input, what is the actual output and what is the expected output? And have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger to see when and where the miscalculations are?

Comment: By the way, you do know that the `return` statement is causing an *immediate* return from the function? No code after a `return` will be executed. And you unconditionally return early from the function in multiple places.

Comment: You'll find code will be a lot easier to maintain/debug if you indent it well. What you currently have is a poorly structured style.

Comment: How do you know that polynomials always have integer roots? (root1 and root2 are int). 
Indentation is a good way to make source code better understandable.

Comment: Apologies for the poor indentation, but I am fairly new to this community and I'm still getting used to formatting / indentation when posting.

Comment: `int a, b, c, d, root1, root2;`-> `double a, b, c, d, root1, root2;` and possibly a few other problems.

Comment: Please edit your post to fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("%.3f+%.3fi", ((-b) / (2*a)), (sqrt(d) / (2 * a)));
```

You are using integer division in `((-b) / (2*a))` So you will get incorrect values for some numbers.

You can use.

```
printf("%.3f+%.3fi", ((-b) / (2.0*a)), (sqrt(d) / (2 * a)));
```

to force a conversion to a double before the division. You need to do this for all division between two integers in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The design of this programm is horrific, but if you

- add `#include <math.h>` (so `sqrt` is known)
- replace all `int`s by `float`s (you don't want integer maths here)
- replace `scanf("%f, %f, %f", &a, &b, &c);` by `scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);` (correct format string for `scanf`).

it should work more or less.

I didn't dig further, so there may be other problems though.